# modify receive buffer size in php soap client request

Tags: php, soap, soap-client

I'm working on `zendframework 2` application. I'm preparing a module where I need to call a webservice using `soapclient`. At first I got result set (say 20 records in DataBase) without a problem. And when large result is set (say 600 records in DataBase), I'm receiving an error:

```
"Looks like we got no xml document".
```

Somebody told me that I have to increase received buffer size. I don't know what is it and where to modify it.